# PDF print to Sticker/Label Thermal Printer [PYTHON]

Tags: python, pdf, printing, label, thermal-printer

I need help in figuring how to print pdfs to sticker/label printers properly.
One-Sticker-Per-Page Printers are working fine currently though printers with multiple labels per row do not work as expected.
Here is my code to generate PDF files:

```py
from PIL import Image
import PyPDF2

img = Image.open('somelabelimage.png', 'r')  # load the image

# calculate pixels from mm
def gpm(mm):
    return round((72 * mm) / 25.4)

img = img.resize(
    (
       gpm(15)*10,gpm(5)*10 # 15mm X 5mm
    ),
    Image.LANCZOS
)


img_w, img_h = img.size

# create empty new PIL.Image
pivot = Image.new('RGB', ( 4*(img_w+ (gpm(4)*10))-(gpm(4)*10), img_h), (255, 255, 255))
x = 0

# here we paste each label-image onto the new surface
for y in range(4):
    pivot.paste(img,(x,0))
    x += img_w + (gpm(4)*10) # 4 mm offset increased by factor 10 

# save the image as pdf
pivot.save("new.pdf",resolution=200)

# code below resizes the pdf file to fit the mm specs
pr = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open('new.pdf','rb'))
pw = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()

def mti(mm):
    return mm / 25.4

page = pr.getPage(0)
page.scaleTo(mti(15)*72*4,mti(5)*72)

pw.addPage(page)
pw.write(open("resized.pdf",'wb'))
```

So this is how I actually print:

```py
import subprocess

# pdftopriter.exe is an exe that lets me print to printers. Here is the link to theri page : # http://www.columbia.edu/~em36/pdftoprinter.html
command = [
  "session/PDFtoPrinter.exe", "storage/storage_export.pdf",
  self.printer if self.printer is not None else "None"
]

subprocess.Popen(command)
```

Result for single-labels:
[image]

So they are workig fine however here is the result for the other printer:
[image]

As you can see this print job is prett off. But I cant figure how to fix/adjust that.

I appreciate every kind of help or advice regarding pdf creation or printing in general.
If you found a better way to print images please help me out!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: A general-purpose technology like PDF is useful if it fits well, but it may not always be available everywhere. It seems that the printer vendor provides the tools and SDK, so be sure to use them.

Comment: Any clues how I utilize the printers vendor if the target printer is not known?( any printer )

Comment: If you have a standard specification that doesn't depend on a particular vendor or model, you can use it. However, the specifications for printing PC cut sheets and receipt roll paper will not be suitable for label printing. I don't know about label printing, so I can't give you any definite advice, but Zebra's ZPL specification may be used a lot. Please search them.